# How to detect whether an html input object is a button or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on trying to pull the inputs from a form, excluding buttons, but not radio buttons. I am getting my inputs via the .find() method of the form element. I have the inputs, but am unable to restrict them to just inputs other than the submit button or a similar button. I have tried the jquery .is(), .type(), both with no luck any suggestions/ references would be helpful as I have not found anything to help as of yet. Here is the code I am using to pull the forms.

```
 var inputs = formList.find(":input");


        if (inputs ? inputs.length > 0 : false)
        {
          for(j = 0;j < inputs.length; j++)
          {
              console.log("input: " + inputs[j]);
              if (inputs[j].name != "")
              { 
                 webForms.push({"inputName": inputs[j].name});  
              }else if (inputs[j].id != "")
              {
                 webForms.push({"inputName": inputs[j].id});  
              } 
          } 
        }
```

Like I said, I have tried the .is and .type with no luck. Here is an example of how I was using .is()

```
var formList = $("form");
var formName = $("form").attr("name");
if (formList != null ? formList.length > 0 : false)
{
  if (formList.length < 2)
  {
    if (formList.attr("name") ? formList.attr("name") != "" : false)
    {
      //alert("form name is not null");
        //alert("form name: " + formList.attr("name"));
        var webForms = [];
        //alert("formList name: " + formList[i]);
        var inputs = formList.find(":input");


        if (inputs ? inputs.length > 0 : false)
        {
          for(j = 0;j < inputs.length; j++)
          {
              console.log("input: " + inputs[j]);
              if (inputs[j].name != "")
              { 
                 if(inputs[j].is(":button"))
                 {
                     console.log(inputs[j].name + " is a button");
                 }
                 webForms.push({"inputName": inputs[j].name});  
              }else if (inputs[j].id != "")
              {
                 if(inputs[j].is(":button"))
                 {
                     console.log(inputs[j].name + " is a button");
                 }
                 webForms.push({"inputName": inputs[j].id});  
              } 
          } 
        }
        //alert(JSON.stringify(webForms));
        jsonForm.forms[jsonForm.forms.length - 1].name = formList.attr("name");
        //alert("json form name: " + JSON.stringify(jsonForm));
        jsonForm.forms[jsonForm.forms.length - 1].inputs = webForms;
        //alert("name: " + jsonForm.forms[jsonForm.forms.length - 1].name);    
    }

  }
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: realized after I posted and revisited .type docs that this was not what I needed. In place of .is in my code I had  .type and passed in a variable filled like such: var b = form.find(":button"). Needless to say this won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get the input elements which aren't `button`s or `input`s with a `type` attribute of "submit".

```
 var inputs = formList.find(':input:not(button, [type="submit"])');
```

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xkpzhnwz) is a live demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is `inputs[i]` returns a dom element reference not a jQuery wrapper object so its does not have the `is` method you can use

```
inputs.eq(i).is(':button')
```

I would recommend to use .each() loop to iterate over the jQuery object than using a loop

```
        var inputs = formList.find(":input");

        inputs.each(function () {
            var $input = $(this);
            console.log("input: " + this);
            if (this.name != "") {
                if ($input.is(":button")) {
                    console.log(this.name + " is a button");
                }
                webForms.push({
                    "inputName": this.name
                });
            } else if (this.id != "") {
                if ($input.is(":button")) {
                    console.log(this.name + " is a button");
                }
                webForms.push({
                    "inputName": this.id
                });
            }
        })
```

---

This could even be simplified to

```
        var inputs = formList.find(":input");

        inputs.each(function () {
            var $input = $(this);
            console.log("input: " + this);

            var name = this.name || this.id;
            if (name != "") {
                if ($input.is(":button")) {
                    console.log(name + " is a button");
                }
                webForms.push({
                    "inputName": name
                });
            }
        })
```